# Antlr left recursion

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm writing a simple language but I have a left recursion that I don't know how to solve.

```
booleanExpression
    : expression EQUALS expression
    ;

numericExpression
    :
    ;

expression
    : booleanExpression
    | numericExpression
    ;
```

As you can see the `booleanExpression` recurses with the `expression` since for e.g this is a boolea expression `1 == 1` and can have anything on each side of the equals and anything in this case is defined by the expression.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Indirect left-recursion isn't supported by ANTLR4, direct left recursion *is* however:

```
expression
    : expression HIGHER_PRECEDENCE_OPERATOR expression
    | expression EQUALS expression
    | expression LOWER_PRECEDENCE_OPERATOR expression
    | ...
    | '(' expression ')'
    | NUMBER
    | STRING
    | ... 
    ;
```